# Hiding content with javascript trouble

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code. As you can see the buttons are hiding the explanations to words. The problem is that I cannot figure out how to start the page with the explanations hidden. I can't wrap my head around this.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 function showHide(divId){
   var theDiv = document.getElementById(divId);
   if(theDiv.style.display=="none"){
    theDiv.style.display="";
   }else{
     theDiv.style.display="none";
   }    
 }
</script>

  <p><b>AMBIVALENT</b>  
<input type="button" onclick="showHide('-1')" value="Hide/Show"> 
<div id = "-1" style="">indecisive, having mixed feelings</div></p>
```

Comment: why `id="-1"` not something simple?

Comment: You could replace your `if` statement with a shorter ternary statement: `theDiv.style.display = theDiv.style.display == "none" ? "" : "none";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

display:none in the style

```
<div id = "-1" style="display:none;">indecisive, having mixed feelings</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the style directly to the div to start out with.

```
<div id = "-1" style="display:none;">indecisive, having mixed feelings</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your code:

```
<p><b>AMBIVALENT</b>  
<input type="button" onclick="showHide('-1')" value="Hide/Show"> 
<div id = "-1" style="">indecisive, having mixed feelings</div></p>
```

Just add the "display" property with value of "none" to the element holding the description. Like so:

```
<div id = "-1" style="display: none">indecisive, having mixed feelings</div></p>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your correctly, you should use this:

```
<div id = "-1" style="display: none">indecisive, having mixed feelings</div></p>
```

Regards